# Mail attachment not work android

Tags: java, android, email-attachments

I tried the following code for attaching images to email. Images may be captured or selected from gallery.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
i.setType("image/*");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@xyz.com"}); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{"ppp@qqq.com"});   
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(email_body));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Vehicle Details");
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Vehicle_images.uris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share"));
```

Here abc@xyz.com and ppp@qqq.com are dummy email ids and Vehicle_images.uris is a array list of uris.

The problem is that i cant to attach images from a Minno tablet, but this works on other devices. Minno tablet runs on Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean). Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/"+"rec1.jpg"); 
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```